# Each & every in negative sentences

Tags: negation

> There are three fruits - an apple, banana and melon. I hate the apple and banana, but I love the melon.

In this case, are the sentences “I don’t hate every fruits of them” and “I don’t hate each fruits of them” interchangeable?

Comment: Neither sentence is at all idiomatic. "I don't hate all those fruits" or "I don't hate every one of them".

Comment: @Kate Bunting What about “I don’t hate each of them”?

Comment: Not idiomatic either. _Each_ is used when something applies to every one individually, not in negative sentences.

Comment: @@Kate Bunting Then, “I don’t hate each of them” means “I hate the melon also”?

Comment: @user02838 Generally, *each* cannot idiomatically be used in negative sentences (with *not*, *don't* etc). It has no meaning. This is actually a proof-reading "Is this right?" question, which is probably more suited to our sister site.

Comment: _I don't hate each of them_ is so un-idiomatic as to be meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

**Neither** of your suggestions are correct, for various reasons.

Firstly, "each" is not really appropriate in the context of your example. The difference between "each" and "every" is that 'each' emphasises the individuality of the items. For example "I gave a gift to every member of my family" could mean you gave *one* gift for them all collectively, whereas "I gave a gift to *each* member of my family" specifically means one gift per person. In your example, "not hating every fruit" is like saying you hate *some* of them, but not all, so this is not something you can apply to 'each' of them individually.

Secondly, "them" refers to '*the fruits*', so you're referring to them twice, and incorrectly.

You should instead say:

> - I don't hate every one of them.

Or

> - I don't hate all of them.